Service Worker isn't called for video sources in Firefox
I have a rather quirky Firefox behavior, I can't explain. Imagine those two very simple HTML tags:
<img src="http://localhost:1234/api/getBlob?file=1.jpg">...
<video src="http://localhost:1234/api/getBlob?file=2.mp4">...

I wrote a service worker that adds the JWT to the Authorization Header as my backend isn't public.
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  const url = event.request.url.toLowerCase();
  if (!url.includes('api/getblob')) {
    return;
  }

  if (event.request.headers.has('Authorization')) {
    return;
  }

  event.respondWith(
    (async function () {
      const token = await requestTokenFromMainThread();
      const headers = new Headers(event.request.headers);
      headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
      const modifiedRequestInit = {
        headers: headers,
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'omit',
      };

      const modifiedRequest = new Request(event.request, modifiedRequestInit);

      try {
        return fetch(modifiedRequest);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching resource:', error);
        return new Response('Error fetching resource', { status: 500 });
      }
    })(),
  );
});

function requestTokenFromMainThread() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const channel = new MessageChannel();
    channel.port1.onmessage = (event) => {
      resolve(event.data);
    };
    self.clients.matchAll().then((clients) => {
      if (clients && clients.length) {
        clients[0].postMessage('requestToken', [channel.port2]);
      }
    });
  });
}

This works great with Safari and Chromium-based browsers (like Edge or Chrome itself). But it starts to get quirky with Firefox. While <img src is handled by the service worker,  <video src isn't and I never ever land inside the fetch function. So I put a debug point at const url = event.request.url.toLowerCase(); this will never be hit with a <video src but will be hit with <img src, and I am not sure why.
EDIT 1:
In Firefox, if I go to the request in question and click "Use as fetch in console" - then, as almost expected, it works like a charm.

The "fix" for that problem in Firefox is to add the crossorigin="anonymous" attribute to the video tag:
<video src="..." crossorigin="anonymous"></video>

In any case, I did open a ticket for Firefox as I am not sure this is the intended behavior if crossorigin isn't defined.
Ticket: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1923096
